# Selecting value from the drop-down using Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
select s =new select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
s.selectByVisibleText("INDIA");
```

and

```
await driver.findElement(By.name('country')).getText(INDIA).click();
```

I have tried these two conditions but with both I get an error message.

Can you help me out this?

Comment: Can you provide the actual error messages? It's hard for us to help you if we don't know what error is actually occuring. Also note that you can make text appear is code by using a backtick (`) or indenting it

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```js
const element = await driver.findElement(By.name('country'));
//const children = await element.findElements(By.tagName('option'));
await element.findElement(By.xpath('option[@value="INDIA"]')).click();
```

Comment: Good for you. Please check to close this question.